# Mysql - check for any children pointing to parent

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Table_A:
id
parent_id
```

Where parent_id refers to id on the same table.

When selecting from this table, I wish to know if the record has any other records pointing to it's id as parent_id. For example

```
Record A
id: 1
parent_id: NULL

Record B
id: 2
parent_id: 1

Record C
id: 3
parent_id: 1
```

When selecting Record A, I'd like to know that it has children, I don't care about how many at this point, just that it has them. The query is fairly optimized already so I'd ideally avoid further queries afterthefact.

So far I've tried joining the record onto it's children, however that then fetches back multiple of the same record if it has multiple children. I've also tried to COUNT the children it joins onto, however this then means I only ever get 1 record back when fetching the Record Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) > 0 AS has_childs
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING t1.id = 1
```

To get all records (without filter), you can use the following solution:

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) > 0 AS has_childs
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

---

In case you need the number of childrens in your application too you can use the following solutions:

```
-- using a filter
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS has_childs
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING t1.id = 1

-- without a filter
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS has_childs
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73ca28d5a7a1c7d8b085c7e282801872)

Comment: Ah - this would be fine except my query needs to fetch back multiple records at the same time, so the WHERE clause would be dropped and at that point because I'm using COUNT in select I'd only ever get back one record. 

`SELECT t1.id, <t1.has_children> FROM table_name` for a crappy example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Adding the GROUP BY to my existing query sorted the issue for me, thanks very muchly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `EXISTS` correlated subquery to see if any other row in the table has that row's `id` value as a `parent_id`:

```
SELECT id,
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_A a2 WHERE a2.parent_id = a1.id) AS has_children
FROM Table_A a1
```

Another way to do it which would probably have better performance is to use a self `LEFT JOIN` on `parent_id` to `id` and check that there is a non-`NULL` value in the joined table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.id,
       NOT ISNULL(a2.id) AS has_children
FROM Table_A a1
LEFT JOIN Table_A a2 ON a2.parent_id = a1.id
ORDER BY a1.id
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fcd0f65991a9bf0adb22b2757bc97f5b)

Comment: Nice solution! I'm using the other answer as it simply required me to add a GROUP clause to what I've got already, but this would also be fine. I'm swapping from COUNT to EXISTS though as that's more semantic.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle it's likely a `JOIN` will be have higher performance too. Note that you will need to use `DISTINCT` if you remove grouping. See my alternate query and demo.